how to use ffmpeg to small size file .ts
How do I ensure that .ts files are no larger than 1024Kbps..?
I use this code
ffmpeg -i https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI20192708/master.m3u8 -c:v libx264 -preset medium -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 0 output.m3u8

, but the file is still large, the results can even be above 5MB
enter image description here

By lowering the quality. Targeting a specific file size is only possible with 2-pass encoding or constant bitrate encoding.

1024Kbps is a per second value, not a total value as your link appears to show.

Can the per second value for each .ts file, sir?

If your 5MB files are no longer than 40 seconds duration the average bitrate will be no greater than 1024Kbps. ....1024bits/8=128bytes. 40×128bytes=5MB

any solution sir?
